# Get data from a FORM in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i need to get data from a `FORM` . My form is :

```
<form action="" id="test">
   <h2>Data</h2>
   <label for="">Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="name">
   <label for="">address</label>
   <input type="text" name="address">
   <label for="">phone</label>
   <input type="text" name="phone">
   <input type="button" onclick="xd()" value="click here">
</form>
```

And for this i used this javascript command :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function xd(){
 //var x=document.forms["test"].getElementsByTagName("address") or
 var x=document.forms["test"].getElementsByTagName("address").value
 document.write(x);
 }
 </script>
```

But it's not working. How to get it easily.

Comment: You don't have tag "address" in your example.

Comment: so, how do i get input data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be targeting an element by its `name` attribute (address), not by its `tagName` attribute.

`.getElementsByTagName` finds all elements in the container that have the specific `tagName`...meaning the `tagName` for a `<a href="#">asdf</a>` element is "a".

I would use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function xd(){
        var inputs = document.forms["test"].getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i = 0 ; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].name === "address") {
                // `inputs[i]` is the element with the name "address"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

You have to loop through the results, and compare the matched elements' `name` attribute against what you want..."address".

Of course, another option is to use `getElementsByName("address")`, like:

```
var address = document.forms["test"].getElementsByName("address");
if (address.length > 0) {
    // `address[0]` is the element with the name "address"
}
```

And a final option is to use `querySelectorAll('input[name="address"]')`, like:

```
var address = document.forms["test"].querySelectorAll('[name="address"]');
if (address.length > 0) {
    // `address[0]` is the element with the name "address"
}
```

Comment: i tried it, but showing `[object HTMLInputElement]`  all time. 
don't know why .

Comment: o ya, got it. i need to add `.value` . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have tag "address".Instead of name put id.It is easy for u

```
 <input type="text" name="address" id="addressId">
var x=document.forms["test"].getElementsById("addressId").value
```

or use

```
var inputs = document.forms["test"].getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0 ; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].name === "address") {
                // `inputs[i]` is the element with the name "address"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `getElementsByName("address")[0]`?

Comment: i just need to get data. i am newbie in javascript.

Comment: You mean the text in the textbox `<input type="text" name="address">`? Change `.getElementsByTagName("address")` to `.getElementsByName("address")[0]` will do.

Comment: i did it . no result.